# Got error &{NOT_FOUND} after joining a recently created channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am running a custom Hyperledger Fabric network that follows this arquitecture:

- org1

  - peer0 (*anchor*)
  - peer1
  - orderer0
- org2

  - peer0 (*anchor*)
  - peer1
  - orderer0
- org3

  - orderer0

Once deployed, everything seems to work correctly. But, if I create a channel and join it from each one of the peers, I get the following log warning in them. Even when it is a warning, I guess it means that is not working correctly.

```
2019-10-07 10:38:17.323 UTC [blocksProvider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 044 [global] Got error &{NOT_FOUND}
```

No errors are shown on the CLI (when I join the channel) neither on the orderers, but there is some activity in these ones after the peers join the channel, so the change is detected. The channel name is `global` and includes all the organizations and peers.

This is the complete log (without gossip or grpc messages):

```
2019-10-07 10:38:10.875 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 024 [][ae2945c0] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc" 
2019-10-07 10:38:10.877 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 025 Creating ledger [global] with genesis block
2019-10-07 10:38:10.886 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 026 Getting block information from block storage
2019-10-07 10:38:10.899 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 027 Created state database global_
2019-10-07 10:38:10.960 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 028 [global] Committed block [0] with 1 transaction(s) in 60ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=7ms state_commit=52ms) commitHash=[]
2019-10-07 10:38:10.961 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 029 Created ledger [global] with genesis block
2019-10-07 10:38:10.997 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 034 system chaincode lscc/global(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2019-10-07 10:38:10.998 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 035 Init CSCC
2019-10-07 10:38:10.998 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 036 system chaincode cscc/global(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2019-10-07 10:38:10.998 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 037 Init QSCC
2019-10-07 10:38:10.998 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 038 system chaincode qscc/global(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) deployed
2019-10-07 10:38:10.998 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 039 system chaincode (+lifecycle,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lifecycle) disabled
2019-10-07 10:38:10.998 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 03a [][ae2945c0] Exit chaincode: name:"cscc"  (123ms)
2019-10-07 10:38:17.002 UTC [blocksProvider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 040 [global] Got error &{NOT_FOUND}
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the NOT_FOUND warning? I have not tried to follow and deploy chaincode but I am pretty sure it is not going to work.

Thank you for your help.

---

*Update:* This is my *configtx.yaml* file:

```
Capabilities:
  Global: &ChannelCapabilities
    V1_3: true
  Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V1_1: true
  Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V1_3: true
Organizations:
- &org1
  Name: org1
  ID: org1MSP
  MSPDir: /data/orgs/org1/msp
  AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org1MSP.member')"
    Writers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org1MSP.member')"
    Admins:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org1MSP.admin')"
  AnchorPeers:
    - Host: peer0.org1
      Port: 7051
- &org2
  Name: org2
  ID: org2MSP
  MSPDir: /data/orgs/org2/msp
  AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org2MSP.member')"
    Writers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org2MSP.member')"
    Admins:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org2MSP.admin')"
  AnchorPeers:
    - Host: peer0.org2
      Port: 7051
- &org3
  Name: org3
  ID: org3MSP
  MSPDir: /data/orgs/org3/msp
  AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org3MSP.member')"
    Writers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org3MSP.member')"
    Admins:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org3MSP.admin')"
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: kafka
  Addresses:
    - orderer0.org1:7050
    - orderer0.org2:7050
    - orderer0.org3:7050
  BatchTimeout: 2s
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
  MaxChannels: 0
  Kafka:
    Brokers:
      - bootstrap.kafka:9092
  Organizations:
      - *org1
      - *org2
      - *org3
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *OrdererCapabilities
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  ACLs: &ACLsDefault
    lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers
    lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers
    lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers
    lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers
    cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
    cscc/GetConfigTree: /Channel/Application/Readers
    cscc/SimulateConfigTreeUpdate: /Channel/Application/Readers
    peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers
    peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Readers
    event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers
    event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
  Organizations:
  Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Profiles:
  OrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
      - *org1
      - *org2
      - *org3
      Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
      - *org1
      - *org2
      - *org3
      Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
        - *org1
        - *org2
  OrgsChannel:
    Capabilities:
      <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
      - *org1
      - *org2
      Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Comment: error indicates that its not able to find channel can you provide the steps that you are following.

Comment: First, for each org I start RCA and ICAs and register an admin and peers/orderers. I start the peers and the orderer without a genesis.block. Then I generate from outside a configtx.yaml file, a genesis.block and a channel.tx using the ICAs ca-chain.pem. Then I connect from a CLI to each peer and run `peer join channel -b genesis.block`.

Comment: I also tried to start the orderers with the genesis.block set but then I got the message `UTC [blocksProvider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 054 [global] Got error &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}`.

Comment: peer cannot join system channel, genesis block is only for orderer you should go through readthedocs to clear concept of how hyperledger fabric works.

Comment: @mohammedrampurawala Can you be more deep about it? In readthedocs I see that the command to join a channel is `peer channel join -b <genesis_block>`. So I do not get why you say that it is only for the orderer. Also, I am not trying to join any system channel but a custom channel I created with the configtx that you have in the main post. If you can be more specific or redirect me to more concise documentation I would be really grateful.

Comment: @mohammedrampurawala Oh, I think I see it. I am joining the channel using the genesis block and I should be using the channel tx. Isn't it?

Comment: you should create channel first from channel.tx file once channel is created you will be able to see file channel.block pass this file is peer channel join command

Comment: @mohammedrampurawala If works (I have advanced to a new error haha). If you add it as a answer, I can accept it so it can help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are using genesis block to join channel instead when you create channel using file channel.tx a file would be generated named channel.block pass that in your peer channel join command

```
peer channel join -b channel.block
```